# Grails unit test fails sometime

Tags: unit-testing, grails-2.0

I have unit test which in setup creates 4 users (mocked).
Everything was fine until I upgraded to grails 2.2.4.

Now, sometimes the test only creates the last users, and then fails on asserts (naturally).

Has anybody been in the situation?

I have looked at test pollution, but the test order (when it creates all 4 users vs only last user) is the same!

Comment: Code? Really can't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was missing to mock some domain class. I just added the class in the @Mock annotation, and everything is working normally now.